# Problema usar o print para mostrar resultado da função

Tags: python, funções, classificação

Estou criando uma função que embaralha e devolve a palavra digitada, porém não sei como usar o `print` (se realmente for esse o caso) para mostrar o resultado da função abaixo:

```
def f():
    a = []
    x = 0
    while x < len(word):
        a.append(word[x])
        x += 1
        if x > len(word):
            break
    return a.sort()



word = input()
f()
'''Aqui ficaria o print. Seria algo parecido com "print(f())"? Tentei exatamente isso e a resposta foi "None".'''
```

Comment: Primeiramente ajuda saber *como você está estudando*, para que possamos entender aquilo que já não está sendo muito eficaz, para que então finalmente possamos diversificar idéias e tentar ajudar de verdade.

Comment: Bom, estou preferindo estudar por cursos online(gratuitos), já que a maioria dos livros de Python estão em Inglês. Dos assuntos que já estudei, tenho certeza de ter aprendido apenas operadores lógicos, variáveis, estruturas de repetição, de controle, strings e listas. E sempre que aprendi um desses eu passei para o próximo, porém quando surge alguns comandos mais específicos como o sorted ou os recursos da biblioteca random que nem sempre são introduzidos nos cursos online, ou até apenas entender porque que um determinado erro ocorreu, aí já começo a ver minhas dificuldades.

Comment: Revisei tudo que eu achei que sabia, escolhi outros cursos online pra estudar, e mesmo que eu queira fazer um exercício(como esse da pergunta) eu não avanço enquanto eu não souber tudo que eu preciso pra poder fazê-lo. Achei um bom livro sobre o Básico do Python em Português e estou lendo-o, acho que agora estou no caminho certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema na verdade está em:

```
 return a.sort()
```

O método `sort()` ele ordena a list em ordem crescente porém ele não retorna nenhum valor (`None`). Então quando você tenta imprimir o retorno da função `f()` você imprime justamente o seu retorno: `None`.

Se quiser imprimir a lista ordenada, seu código ficaria assim:

```
def f():
    a = []
    x = 0
    while x < len(word):
        a.append(word[x])
        x += 1

    a.sort()    
    return a



word = input()
print(f())
```

Answer (score 4):

O que está querendo fazer é classificar e não embaralhar. Ou se quiser embaralhar está errado.

Basta fazer isto:

```
print(''.join(sorted(input())))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Sorting.py).

Claro que essa forma não é robusta, mas o original não se preocupava com robustez. Qualquer digitação errada e não funciona.